# How to make a bitwise array move one index every 30 seconds in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am rather new to coding and need some help with creating an array that will move to the next index every 30 seconds in C using byte operators. The goal is to be able to iterate to the next index and then loop back to the first index in 3000 second intervals. Im sort of stuck on how to proceed but any luck or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you to anyone willing to help.

```
array[3] = {var1|var2, var1|var2, var1|var3};
msleep(3000);
array[i++];
printf("The array is currently this: %d\n", array[i]
```

Comment: 30 seconds or 3000 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array has 3 elements, you can increment the index modulo 3:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 3

int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {var1|var2, var1|var2, var1|var3};
unsigned i = 0;

while(true)
{
  printf("The array is currently this: %d\n", array[i]);
  i = (i + 1) % ARRAY_SIZE;
  sleep(3);
  // when to break is up to you.
}
```

EDIT: Addressing your comment

It's perfectly valid to use an `if` statement to reset the array index, however, I'm not quite following your logic in the comment.  Don't forget, in C, arrays begin at index 0, not 1.  You do not need to use an `if` statement *and* modular division.  Using an `if` statement would go something like

```
while(true)
{
  printf("The array is currently this: %d\n", array[i]);
  if (i + 1 >= ARRAY_SIZE)
  {
    i = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    i++;
  }
  sleep(3);
  // when to break is up to you.
}
```

This may even squeak out some better performance, but considering a 3 second sleep is acceptable, probably negligible (you'd have to benchmark it to know for sure).

Another thing to consider when using the modulo approach, and rightly so, is wrap around.  An `unsigned int` on your system is most likely 4 bytes, meaning it has a max value of 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, or 4294967295.  It turns out this is evenly divisible by 3, so consider what happens when you get to the upper limits of an `unsigned int`:

```
4294967293 % 3 == 1
4294967294 % 3 == 2
4294967295 % 3 == 0   // <== MAX UNSIGNED INT, +1 wraps it back to 0
0          % 3 == 0
1          % 3 == 1
// etc
```

This means, that if you were to wrap around, you would get index 0 twice in a row.  If that's unacceptable, you definitely want to use the "`if` statement" method.  However, there will be `4294967295 / 3 == 1431655765` iterations before wrap around, and considering your 3 second sleep, that will take more than 136 years to occur, according to my math.  There's not a computer system that's ever been conceived expected to run for that long, so you're perfectly safe using the modulo approach for all practical purposes.

Comment: Does that mean that I can use an if-statement to loop back to the first index when I get to index 3?
something like:

   printf("The array is currently this: %d \n", array[i]);
   if (i % ARRAY_SIZE != 0)
   {
      i = (i+1) % ARRAY_SIZE;
   }
   else
   {
     i =1;
   }
   sleep(3);

Comment: @tora231 see my edit

Comment: Thank you this gives me a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

```c
array[3] = {var1|var2, var1|var2, var1|var3};

while (1)
{       
    array[++i % 3];  /* answer */
    printf("The array is currently this: %d\n", array[i]);
    msleep(3000);
}
```

The `++` must precede the variable to be performed before expression is evaluated.

When `++` precedes the variable, it is being used as a "prefix operator".